# Chromium crashes when opening multiple YouTube tabs?

Tags: 20.04, chromium, crash, youtube, flatpak

I'm using Chromium Browser (93.0.4577.82 -- Flatpak) on Ubuntu 20.04, and recently I've noticed that the browser constantly crashes under this specific scenario:

1. Open Chromium and open a new Incognito window
2. Go to YouTube and start playing any video
3. Open another YouTube tab

Chromium then crashes. I tried restarting (no luck) and checking memory usage (I have plenty), but the issue persists.

I can't tell if this is related to a bug in YouTube or Chromium, but I haven't observed this happening even a few days ago. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**, I also faced this issue with Chromium, But after some research I have found that its not the browser issue, its the Flatpak issue. SO I uninstall the Chromium through Flatpak and installed it with **Snap software package**.
Currently, I'm using Chromium Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).

I hope this will fix your issue.